# cast to objectId failed for value xxx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoDB populate model and when I try to save the data inside the schema it throws an error:

```
 message:    'Cast to ObjectId failed for value
```

this is my schema

```
jobSiteInformation: {
    buildingName: String,
    street: String,
    city: String,
  },
  data: [{
    ref: 'data',
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  }],
```

phase schema is like this

```
const listSchema= new Schema({
  name: String,
  progress: Number,
  list: [],
});
```

this phase schema is array inside phases which is the quite large and thats the reason I moved to populate model.

anyway this is my route and when I run this it throws the error I pasted above.

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const info= new List({
    jobSiteInformation: req.body.jobSiteInformation,
  });
  try {
    const install = req.body.list;
      install.map((inst) => info.lists.push(inst));
    const saved= await partial.save();
    return res.status(201).json({
      result: saved,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return next(e);
  }
});
```

I have tried to google but I cannot find the what I am looking for. I have read other posts too but cannot understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your jobSiteInformation schema has `installations` property as array of object ids. So you have to save the installations first, then add the inserted `_id` into `partial.installations` array, then save the `partials`

Comment: can you explain it bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming mongoose model for phase schema is `Phase`

```
// import Phase from ../models/phase
router.post('/request/partial', async (req, res, next) => {
  const partial = new PartialRequest({
    jobSiteInformation: req.body.jobSiteInformation,
  });
  try {
    const install = req.body.installations;
    let savedPhases = await Phase.insertMany(install); // TODO: handle error case
    savedPhases.map((inst) => partial.installations.push(inst["_id"]));
    const savedPartials = await partial.save();
    console.log(savedPartials);
    return res.status(201).json({
      result: savedPartials,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return next(e);
  }
});
```